# C# Converting a var/string to action

Tags: c#, system.reflection

My command system works off a database where the entire command is stored.

In the Command creation, the

```
.SetAction((t, m, c) => { //code });
```

is what the command actually does.

Pulling from the db, this comes in as a var.

How would I go about converting this to actual code for the Action to actually handle?

Reading through a couple pages from Google leaves me to believe I'll need to use Reflection which I've only touched on with Interfaces.

Snippet of the `SetAction`

```
public Command SetAction(Action<string, Message, DiscordClient> action)
{
    this.action = action;
    return this;
}
```

The code I am using looks like this:

```
using (var command = sql.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM commands";
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        var actionCol = reader.GetOrdinal("action");

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var action = reader.GetValue(acionCol);

            cm.AddCommand(new Command()
                .SetAction((t, m, c,) => {  }));
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Reflection can be used to execute code that you know exists in a compiled assembly. It cannot interpret code, which is what you're looking to do here. You would need to actually create a C# class library complete with namespaces and such, compile, and then call that compiled assembly to get the behavior you're after.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [evaluate code inline (or using reflection)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285360/evaluate-code-inline-or-using-reflection)

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean as a `var` - in the context of *Pulling from the db, this comes in as a var*? How do you store it in the database? Is it a string of C# code? Binary?

Comment: It's stored as text in the db. The method I'm using to pull it returns as a var. I'm using MySqlDataReader

Comment: @TehPirate `var` is not a type, which is what I'm getting at. `var` in C# simply tells the compiler to automatically detect the type. Can you show the code loading the text? Can you show us the type of text you're saving?

Comment: @Rob http://i.imgur.com/Pi9yxTk.png

Comment: What does a value from the DB look like?

Comment: @MattRowland `m.Channel.SendMessage("Hello:);`

Comment: Is that the `string` value stored in a `VARCHAR` column?

Comment: @MattRowland It's stored as TEXT in the DB but the method I used to pull the DB returns as a var.

Comment: As @Rob stated before `var` is not a type. It is just a way to let to compiler decide the type.